# How to retrieve the "hasmany" relationship for a model from the back-end in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models defined in Ember and also in a Rails application:

```
App.Library = DS.Model.create({
  books: DS.hasMany('App.Book')
});
App.Book = DS.Model.create({
  library: DS.belongsTo('App.Library')
});
```

On the back-end side, I have several Book for each Library, I would like to retrieve those books but there is no back-end call when I do this (library object is correct and has an id that match its id on the back-end):

```
var libraryBooks = library.get("books");
```

I am expecting a back-end call to my rails API in order to fetch all books for this specific library, but instead I just get the empty `Ember.OrderedSet` without back-end call.

I am starting with Ember so maybe this is not correct, if this is the case, what is the best way to retrieve the "hasmany" for a given model directly from the back-end if you only have the model's id?

Comment: Could you paste an example of your json?

Comment: The issue is there is no back-end call at all, so I'm not yet receiving JSON (which is correctly formatted and not relevant for the moment).

Comment: did what I proposed work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.find()` will make ember do a request.

```
App.Library.find(1/* the id of the library*/).get('books');
```

it'll to a request to `/librarys/1` i think. You can configure the plural like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
    library: "libraries"
});
```

Now the request will be to `/libraries/1`

You could also probably get the books by the library:

```
App.Book.find({library: 1});
```

the `library: 1` you'll have to handle yourself on the backend. emberdata sends it as a querystring. Like this: `/books?library=1`

Have a look [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/) there is some documentation on ember-data